# Docker COPY sh script not working (not found)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i am not new to docker but i mostly work with prebuilt images, that i connect using docker-compose. I need a super-basic container, that only reads log files and streams the contents to stdout because i have permission issues in another container.

See:
https://github.com/webdevops/Dockerfile/issues/332

Anyway - i fail at the very first step and dont know whats the problem

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest
COPY readlogs.sh /root/readlogs.sh
CMD ['/root/readlogs.sh']
```

The sheel script looks like this (at the moment - i am testing)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "hello world"

#cat /dev/null > /var/log/app/error.log
#cat /dev/null > /var/log/app/debug.log

#tail -f /var/log/app/error.log > /dev/stderr &
#tail -f /var/log/app/debug.log > /dev/stdout &
```

As you see i want to truncate some log file and then just read it continously.

Building the image works fine, starting it results in:

```
/bin/sh: [/root/readlogs.sh]: not found
exited with code 127
```

NO - the line endings are not DOS.

My docker-compose.yml

```
  logreader:
    build:
      context: docker/logreader
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./var/logs:/var/log/app
```

So - why the funk cant i execute the readlogs.sh file?

The file is executeable (on the host), i tried adding `RUN chmod +x /root/readlogs.sh` but it did not work either.

Comment: `chmod +x /root/readlogs.sh` and change this `#!/usr/bin/env bash` to `#!/bin/sh`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the file not found issue, you need to replace `CMD ['/root/readlogs.sh']` for `CMD [ "/root/readlogs.sh" ]`. Notice the double quotes and the whitespace.

But even after you fix this one, you would still have another issue which is that you're trying to use `bash` in alpine. So you need to change to `sh` as Linpy said.